# Dynamic wiremock to capture path parameter and return in response

Tags: mocking, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I am trying to create dynamic mocks using WireMock. I have a situation where if I specify URL like

`http://localhost:8989/api/account/121`

then I should receive response like this:

```
   "cycleSpecification": {
       "id": "121"
        }
  }
```

In brief, the path param is returned in the response body, but I am not sure how should I capture 121 and return this in the response using wiremock.

and for this kind of request

```
/myManagement/v1/source?filters=myParty.id==539&&myParty.role==individual
```

OR

```
/myManagement/v1/source?filters=myParty.id%3D%3D539%26myParty.role%3D%individual
```

what can I used so response will filter out the id and role and put in the response.

I am using standalone wiremock jar 2.27.2 to create wiremock-server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using response templating. You'll need to add `--global-response-templating` to how you are starting up your standalone server, and then you can use response templates.

I think you'd want something like:

```
{
  "request" : {
    "urlPathPattern" : "/api/account/.*",
    "method" : "GET"
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "body" : "{ \"cycleSpecification\": { \"id\": \"{{request.path.[2]}}\" } }"
  }
}
```

[Check out the documentation on the request model for more information](http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/#the-request-model)

For your second question, if the query parameters were sent as separate query parameters, you'd be able to reference them with the request model.

```
{
  "request" : {
    "urlPathPattern" : "/api/account/.*",
    "method" : "GET",
    "queryParameters": {
        "myParty.id" : {
            "matches": ".*"
        },
        "myParty.role": {
            "matches": ".*"
        }
    }
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "body" : "{ \"cycleSpecification\": { \"id\": \"{{request.query.party.id}}\" } }"
  }
}
```

Since it doesn't look like you're query parameters are being sent separately, unfortunately, I think you'll need to [create a transformer](http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/#transforming-responses) to modify your response.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can you please help me with the one more kind of request which I added in question. The one with the filter in url. How can i use it. I wanted to add both parameter in json response which are present in filter.

Comment: I've added a response to your second question. Unfortunately, you'll probably need to create a custom transformer to accomplish your goals.